# How to add custom attribute for jquery UI dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I want to add an extra attribute to jquery dialog.

```
$(".pipeline-dialog").dialog({
    dialogClass: "dialog_status,
    autoOpen: false
});
```

how to add an attribute like "dialog-status" when creating dialog.

any methods to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$(".pipeline-dialog").dialog({
    //initial value for custom attribute
    customAttribute: "value"
});

//get value
var customAttrValue = $(".pipeline-dialog").dialog("option", "customAttribute");

//set new value
$(".pipeline-dialog").dialog("option", "customAttribute", "new value");
```